# SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments (parentheses around the arrow-function may help),javascript begginer

Tags: javascript

I have this error and i dont know what to do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSDaU.png)

and this is the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIWmZ.png)

Comment: post the code, not an image of the code

Comment: your forEach line is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
navLinks.forEach(link, index) => {
   //code
}
```

To this:

```
navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
   //code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When there are two parameter and you are using the arrow , you should enclose the parameter in the parenthesis ( ) . See your forEach method .